# Product data update not effective until product is manually updated - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import

When I import product data, for example price updates, these values are imported and show up when I view the products in the back end, but I cannot sort on the new prices in the front or back end.

If I go to the edit screen for the products and click update (without changing data) the new price is now available for sorting. I have found that you can do the same thing with the bulk update in the back end, and that saves a bit of time, but I am working with too many products now, so I need to find what's going wrong.

I have had this issue with several different WooCommerce set ups, including a fresh WooCommerce install, so I don't think it is theme or plugin related.

Does anyone have any ideas where I could be doing wrong, or know a way to "re-save" all my products in one go?

Comment: Have you already looked at the `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` table? This table is used for some price caching and you may be running into lookups that use this table.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the price of your products in bulk by using a WooCommerce [product import-export plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/).  [How to bulk update price in WooCommerce](https://www.webtoffee.com/how-to-bulk-update-price-in-woocommerce/)
You can update the price of simple, variable, grouped or any types of products using this WooCommerce extension.